# Running Android application on device via ethernet

Tags: android, testing, device

I have a problem concerning my Android device. I use a ethernet cable to connect my Android tablet to my PC. I don't see any new devices detected by my PC. Is there some configuration  which needs doing? Additionally, how can I run my app on device itself using Eclipse.

Comment: Do you mean USB cable not ethernet cable?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have debugging turned on in the settings of the phone.  Make sure debugging is set to true in the project manifest and make sure you have the correct drivers for the device.

Answer (score 1):

if you are win user you need to install driver if you are linux user than

cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

and add the the ids

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

complete list [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Answer (score 1):

1.Check whether the cable is working fine by using it to connect other devices.
2.Install the correct drivers for the device.
  - Cancel windows update install if you have already downloaded a set of drivers needed.
3.Once the phone gets detected from the PC Wait for 5 min (till the time eclipse recognizes it) and then run it selecting the device as a target.